# Exception generating PDF from Apache FOP with table column

Tags: pdf, formatting, xsl-fo, apache-fop

The below Lines of Code from my .fo file throw a message as
*"The column-number or number of cells in the row overflows the number of fo:table-columns specified for the table."* when  converting the fo to PDF using Apache FOP

<fo:table-column column-width="5.82in" /><fo:table-column column-width="156pt" />

Removing the lines from .fo file and able to generate the PDF using Apache FOP successfully. What value  should be given for column-width so my PDF is generated with out deleting the lines of code.

Comment: Post more code like the whole table. No one can guess without giving ample information.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two columns, but the error message indicates that at least one table row either has more than two table cells or has an `fo:table-cell` with `column-number` greater than `2`.

Either add enough `fo:table-column` for every column in the table or find the table row(s) with more `fo:table-cell` than you expect.